# Parameters for different output

Tags: powershell, parameters

I have a script that's querying a csv, this is working great.  I'm using a parameter to input the users name that I'm looking for.  The output is a complete list of all the machines the user has logged into.  I've modified the same script to only show the last entry in the csv.  Instead of having two scripts for this I'd like to add a parameter to either show all the results or just the last.  I'm fairly new to parameters so I'm not too sure how I should approach this.

```
Param(
[Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
[string]$Username
)

$csv = Import-Csv \\share\dfs\Users\Logon\Logon.csv
$csv | ? {$_.username -eq $Username} | % {

New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
ComputerName = $_.computername 
"Logon Date" = $_.date
 } 
}
```

modified script for last entry in csv

```
Param(
[Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
[string]$Username
)

$csv = Import-Csv \\share\dfs\Users\Logon\Logon.csv
$array = $csv | ? {$_.username -eq $Username} | % {

New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
ComputerName = $_.computername 
"Logon Date" = $_.date
 } 
}
$array[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `switch` parameter, which is `$false` by default, and `$true` if it is specified when calling the script. Based on the value of this `switch` parameter, you can output **all** items, or just the **last** item.

```
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Username
    # Added a new switch parameter. Switch parameters are $false by default.
    # If switch parameter is present, then it will be $true.
    , [switch] $ShowLastOnly
)

$csv = Import-Csv \\share\dfs\Users\Logon\Logon.csv
$array = $csv | ? {$_.username -eq $Username} | % {

New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
ComputerName = $_.computername 
"Logon Date" = $_.date
 } 
}

# If $ShowLastOnly is $true, then ...
if ($ShowLastOnly) {
    $array[-1]; # Output only the last item
}
else {
    $array; # Else ... output all items
}
```

Comment: Sweet I like your process, mine was a bit redundant.

Answer (score 0):

This worked, not sure if anyone has a better solution

```
Param(
[Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
[string]$Username,
[switch]$Last
)

if($Last){
$csv = Import-Csv \\corporate\dfs\Users\Logon\Logon.log
$array = $csv | ? {$_.username -eq $Username} | % {

New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
ComputerName = $_.computername 
"Logon Date" = $_.date
 } 
}


$array[-1] 
}

else
{

$csv = Import-Csv \\corporate\dfs\Users\Logon\Logon.log
$csv | ? {$_.username -eq $Username} | % {

New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
ComputerName = $_.computername 
"Logon Date" = $_.date
 } 
}

}
```